# Ajax call not hitting action method when uploading file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC application where i used one drag and drop file upload which is working fine and file is uploading in respective folder.

Below is the sample code used for it:

```
<div id="dropZone" style="width:340px; height:200px">
    <b> Drop your files here or</b> 
</div>
<img id="uploadImg" src="~/Content/images/Cloud-File.gif" alt="uploadFile" style="width:297px; height:155px; display:none" />


$('#dropZone').filedrop({
    url: '@Url.Action("UploadFiles","Home")',
    paramname: 'files',
    maxFiles: 5,
    dragOver: function () {
       //change color
    },
    dragLeave: function () {
      //change color
    },
    drop: function () {
       //change color
    },
    afterAll: function () {

    },
    uploadFinished: function (i, file, response, time)
    {
      //creating file size and showing the file name in list
    }
});
```

Below is the controller used for it.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable files)
{
    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
    {
      //save logic
    }
    return Json("All files have been successfully stored.");
}
```

Till here everything is fine no issues after that i added one input file control for manual upload file also.
Below is the jquery ajax call used for it:

```
$("#upload").change(function () {
    var fileInfo = $("#upload").prop('files');
    var fileData = new FormData();
    fileData.append('files',fileInfo[0])
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("UploadFiles", "Home")',
        processData:false,
        // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        // data: { files: fileData},
        dataType: "json",
        async:false,
        success: function (response) { UploadBrowseFile(fileInfo[0]); },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) { alert(xhr.responseText); }
    });
});
```

But it is not hitting the same controller action and process is moving to error function, Due to this manual upload is not working.
Need help.

Comment: Your not sending any data - it needs to be `data: fileData,` and you need to set the `contentType: false,` option.

Comment: Note also your method should be `public ActionResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)`

Comment: I found this issue and uncommented data parameter and content type is still commented. for Action result method it is working with drag and drop function then i don't need to change it i have to make this work with browse file also.

Comment: Did you read my first comment - you need to make both those changes!

Comment: I have made contentType:false but still not hitting the action method.

Comment: And `data: fileData`? (which is not `data: { files: fileData}`)

Comment: That i have told in my previous comment i have uncommneted this code like this:  data: { files: fileData}

Comment: FGS. Read my comments. Its `data: fileData` NOT `data: { files: fileData}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147143/discussion-between-prity-kumari-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your currently not sending any data to the method (the commented code for the `data` option is incorrect), and you have the incorrect `contentType` option for sending `FormData` and it must be set to `false` (the default is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`).

Change the ajax option to

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("UploadFiles", "Home")',
    processData:false,
    contentType: false, // change
    data: fileData, // change
    dataType: "json",
    async:false,
    success: function (response) { UploadBrowseFile(fileInfo[0]); },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) { alert(xhr.responseText); }
});
```

You also need to change the signature of the method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, This solution is worked for me. I am marking it as answer.